# 5.1 audio mix doesn't support rear left and rear right channels

Tags: audio

To,
Blender foundation

Hi. I am Rutu from india.  I am a frequent user of Blender  and would like to ask you that does  the Audio  5.1 Surround mix in the VSE only supports left ,center and right channel with a pan values of -1 ,0 and 1 respectively . The values -2 and 2 were for the extreme left and right (left surround and right surround ) which seems to don't work . The LF CNT RFare working perfectly fine but RL and RR were sounding from front speakers .
I have a 5.1 audio card and a Logitech Z906 Dolby certified speaker system so it should work fine .
I have mono audio files and even enabled the 5.1  surround option in scene tab .

I have also tried to make a scene where I have placed the speaker object at front left front right. Center   rear left and rear right of the camera  . Assigned them mono sources sound and play backed it. But still only front left and front right speaker is sounding correctly . Rear left and rear right sound is coming from front speakers .

When I mix the channels in audacity they sound perfectly from all channels which I have set.

Is there any other option we can do to make hear the separate channels for  rear left and rear right sound in Blender .